# Unobtrusive client side validation message for custom validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I created custom validation in MVC model to check whether EndDate field is greater than StartDate. Like this:

```
public class ViewModel: IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]    
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; } 

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       if (EndDate < StartDate)
       {
           yield return 
             new ValidationResult(errorMessage: "EndDate must be greater than StartDate",
                                  memberNames: new[] { "EndDate" });
       }
    }
}
```

thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882534/3929188) post for showing me how do that.

But this code works in Server side only. It doesn't validates before submitting the form.  Means it doesn't show any error message when i put

> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EndDate)

Can any one help me to make this validation possible in the client side using jquery unobtrusive validation?

Comment: You need to create a class that inherits `ValidationAttribute` and implements `IClientValidatable` - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: it wont show cause you havent defined the jquery method , try adding a jquery method that matches your needs  
 https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/ or create a custom  validation method using js

Comment: @hdriab that's bad practice right? cause you are duplicating the code for same functionality twice - one at model and one at view. I am trying to hold all my business logic with in my model. That's the essence of MVC after all.

Comment: You have to write javascript code for the client side validation. Your browser does not know anything about c# code on the server - it only knows javascript

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yup.. that's right. i was wrong .me just learning ...